# Rails nested attributes with existing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to deal with nested attributes with the usual way:

Model:

```
class InventoryItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end
```

Form:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.fields_for :location do |location| %>
      <%= location.label :location_name %>
      <%= location.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
  def new
    @inventory_item = InventoryItem.new
    @inventory_item.build_location
  end

  def inventory_item_params
    params.require(:inventory_item).permit(:location_id, location_attributes:[:name])
  end
```

My problem is that I want that if the `Location` exists the new `InventoryItem` is associated with it.
I don't now how to rebuild the association between `InventoryItem` and `Location` in case of `Location` with the `name` exists. The:  `@inventory_item.build_location` in the controller is allways creating a new `Location`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `accepts_nested_attributes_for :location` adds a method to your `InventoryItem` model: `location_attributes=`.

You have a special constraint on this method, so you need to override it in inventory_item.rb, something like this:

```rb
#inventory_item.rb
def location_attributes=(attrs)
  begin
    self.location_id = Location.find_by!(name: attrs[:name])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @les-nightingill is a good start, I changed to `self.location` . Can you recommend me some book o resources to learn better more about these kind of internals?  thanks in advance

Comment: @JohnFadria I don't really have a Rails book to suggest. Study closely the Rails docs, most of the answers are there!